# viewForFooterInSection need to set footer fixed absolute position

Tags: iphone, xcode, tableview

I want my footer appear with bottom, in the following image footer binding with grid, i want footer need to fixed at bottom, If tableview rows are more or less.

[image]

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SectionHeader"; 
    //UITableViewCell *headerView = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,300,60)] ;

    UIImage *myImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"top_bar.png"];
    UIImageView *imageView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
    imageView.frame= CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 50);
    [headerView addSubview:imageView];   



    UIButton *circularButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];    
    CGRect circularRect = CGRectMake(5.0, 5, 58.0, 32.0);
    [circularButton setFrame:circularRect];
    [circularButton addTarget:self action:@selector(Meetup:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back_btn.png"];
    [circularButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [headerView addSubview:circularButton];     

    return headerView;
}  

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 50;

}
```

I am using above code. please advised me, thanks

Comment: Your ratio of questions/accepted answers is low. Please, don't be selfish and be grateful with the time people waste here to help you and at least accept a valid answer. People will not help you anymore if they see that you are that selfish.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly what you need to do, which is to **always keep the footer view docked to the bottom of the screen**, my advice is to **take that footer view out** of the tableView and **place it below your tableView**  in its parent view.